# DirectX setup Internal Error when installing Battlefield 4

Tags: battlefield-4, origin

When trying to install BF 4 on my Windows 7 machine I got the following message after a few seconds:

[image: error]

There is no percentage showing, and then, origin get stuck on this:

[image]
The only way to close Origin is through Windows Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc)

Already tried:

1. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 4\ __Installer\directx\redist
2. Delete all the contents of the folder except for the following files: DSETUP.dll dsetup32.dll DXSETUP.exe
3. Install the game again.

Also tried to manually install the DXSETUP.exe but the window appears then vanishes very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

First of try to install Direct X from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35).

Make sure you got this runtime installed http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109.

Update your graphics drivers.

Try to give me some more information about your witch version of Windows you are running. (Looks like Windows 7)

Check out this thread here on EA's site. http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/BF4-stops-installing-at-20-throws-up-a-DirectX-internal-error/td-p/1624145

The dialogue box at the top shows Mass Effect 3 (with the DX Error)[dont know why].

Answer (score 2):

Disable or stop your antivirus then run the Directx setup, the setup should now run smoothly.

Sometimes the Antivirus prevents important files from running.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way for it to work:

1. Create a new folder.
2. Select all files except dsetup.dll, dsetup32.dll, and dxsetup.exe, and instead of dragging them to the new folder you do want to extract all files instead and then drag all the files together with the new files except for dsetup.dll, dsetup32.dll, and dxsetup.exe, and move all the others to the new map you created.
3. Run DXSETUP.exe and after that it will work.